# Websphere Application Server8.5

Tags: websphere

I am trying to install WAS8.5 on vmware but .exe file is not showing in vomx files list.can any one explain how to install WAS8.5 on VMware Workstation?

how to copy files from local system to VMware?

Comment: Can you enumerate the steps you have done to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. This doesn't look like it has anything to do with programming. Are you looking for [sf]?